# How to extend $scope globally?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I would like that all my `$scope` objects contain a specific helper method that I use to retrieve data like `$scope.getData('member.submember.othermember')` otherwise I would have to do `$scope['member']['submember']['othermember']`.

The idea is to add this `.getData` method to all the created `$scope` objects by default.

Is there any extensibility point where I may add that?

Comment: The second version is shorter. There's no need for brackets if you know the names of the properties. There already is such a method.

Comment: If you want to access this way same property from root/parent scope - then you can always make some method there or use shorter notation. If you want access different properties... this is bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular scopes use JS prototypal inheritance, it is possible to add custom method to all scopes (in addition to [existing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) $ methods) with

```
$rootScope.constructor.prototype.$getData = function () { ... };
```

Comment: and you add this to the `app.run(...)` function

Comment: It can be done in $rootScope decorator as well to avoid race conditions.